# How do I define a periodic region?

Tags: plotting, regions

I'm trying to create a region of "thick" grid-lines, like so:

```
GRID = ImplicitRegion[((0 <= x <= 1 || 2 <= x <= 3 || 4 <= x <= 5 || 6 <= x <= 7 || 
   8 <= x <= 9) || (0 <= y <= 1 || 2 <= y <= 3 || 4 <= y <= 5 || 
   6 <= y <= 7 || 8 <= y <= 9)), {{x, 0, 9}, {y, 0, 9}}];
```

which with `RegionPlot[GRID]` produces

[image: plot of GRID]

However, I would like to be able to make my grid an arbitrary size, and arbitrary thickness. So far I have tried using

```
GRID2 = ImplicitRegion[Mod[x, 5] <= 1 || Mod[y, 5] <= 1, {{x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}}]
```

but when I try to plot this, *Mathematica* tells me it's an invalid region to plot. I've also tried `Floor`-ing the x and y prior to `Mod`-ing, but it makes no difference. Are there any suggestions on a better way of doing this?

**EDIT**: It's probably worth pointing out that I plan on using this region as the domain specification of a `ParametricPlot3D`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
r = N @ ImplicitRegion[
   Sin[x Pi] > 0 || Sin[y Pi] > 0, 
   {{x, 0, 9}, {y, 0, 9}}
]

RegionPlot @ r
```

[image]

```
r3 = N @ ImplicitRegion[
   Sin[x Pi] > 0 || Sin[y Pi] > 0 || Sin[z Pi] > 0, 
   {{x, 0, 9}, {y, 0, 9}, {z, 0, 9}}
]

RegionPlot3D[r3, PlotStyle -> Opacity@.5]
```

[image]

So you can play with translation and scaling with:

```
Sin[2 x Pi] > 0 || Sin[.5 (y + 1) Pi] > 0
```

[image]

Comment: Also works with `SquareWave[x/2] > 0 || SquareWave[y/2] > 0`, but the timings are horrible - 24s vs 0.4s for the `Sin` version.

Comment: The meshes are different too: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0WeFJ.png

Comment: @shrx Can't make that work on 10.3.1: `ImplicitRegion[
 SquareWave[x/2] > 0 || SquareWave[y/2] > 0, {{x, 0, 9}, {y, 0, 9}}]` and the dense mesh you see for `SquareWave` is there for `Sin` appraoch.

Comment: interesting, seems like a regression. I have 10.2.0 on OS X.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an idea based on graphics primitives instead of mathematical inequalities.

```
columnWidth = 1;
regionSize = 10;
holes = Table[
   Rectangle[{x, y}, {x + columnWidth, y + columnWidth}],
   {x, columnWidth, regionSize, 2 columnWidth},
   {y, columnWidth, regionSize, 2 columnWidth}
   ];
holes // Graphics
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we subtract these squares from a larger square that covers all of the area:

```
RegionDifference[
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {regionSize + columnWidth, regionSize + columnWidth}],
  RegionUnion[holes]
  ] // RegionPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but here's how the `Mod[]` version should have been implemented:

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[! (1 < Mod[x, 2] < 2 && 1 < Mod[y, 2] < 2), {{x, 0, 9}, {y, 0, 9}}];
RegionPlot[ir]
```

[image: some grid]

A 3D version, just like in Kuba's answer:

```
ir3 = ImplicitRegion[! (1 < Mod[x, 2] < 2 && 1 < Mod[y, 2] < 2 && 1 < Mod[z, 2] < 2),
                     {{x, 0, 9}, {y, 0, 9}, {z, 0, 9}}];
RegionPlot3D[ir3, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]]
```

[image: a 3D grid]

---

> It's probably worth pointing out that I plan on using this region as the domain specification of a `ParametricPlot3D`.

In such a case, it is often more efficient to do preprocessing with `(Boundary)DiscretizeRegion[]` before using it as a plotting region.